# VS 2008 Open Web Site takes forever!

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Anyone else get this or suffer from this?  I am using Vista and VS 2008 and when I goto open a Web Site it literally takes 2~3 minutes for the dialog box to show up.  Once i actually select a website it's not a problem but getting to that point hangs VS really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you're hitting an issue similar to this:

> http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2006/11/27/532465.aspx

Might be worth attaching the debugger to VS to see what it's doing, it may not be the same issue, but you should get some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is stored on your local hard drive.  Storing solutions on a UNC (network path) makes Visual Studio do some weird checking.  I thought this was fixed in VS 2008 SP1, I may be wrong though.  Try out SP1 if you don't have it.

Comment: it is on my local drive and I am using SP1, it's so frustrating: file > open web site > go brew coffee

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I can't offer a solution on Vista but, after experiencing the same thing, I switched back to XP and the problem went away.  You might even want to do what some of our other technical folks do: stay on Vista but run XP in a virtual machine.  Assuming that you have plenty of RAM, you'll notice minimal performance impact on reasonably new computers.