# VS2008: Projects now take forever to open

Tags: visual-studio-2008

yesterday afternoon Visual Studio 2008 suddenly started taking a really long time to open ASP.NET (Web Forms) projects, after several months with no problems.

This problem seemed to begin after I tried adding references to "CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.dll" and "CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.dll" to my main work project. However, every project now suffers from this lag--even ASP.NET test projects with only a default page and no other VS instances running, and my main project with those references removed.

I don't know if the CrystalDecisions thing is a coincidence or not, but that's when this started, and persisted even after removing the references and in new, empty projects.

By default I open VS with an empty environment (no Web start page) and this happens quickly--it's opening any project that now takes minutes to complete.

Something that may matter: this is on a network with no Internet access, so if VS is suddenly looking outside for something it wasn't before, even when opening an empty test project with no references, that could be a problem.

Stuff I tried:

1. Uninstalled/reinstalled VS2008 (and SP1)
2. Attached debugger from one VS instance to another loading test project and monitored native/managed code (per: [Visual Studio Freezing On Opening Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710408/visual-studio-freezing-on-opening-project))
3. Ensured Tools|Options|Debugging|Symbols has no external references
4. Went through Tools|Options looking for any other external references (Environment|Startup is clear, for example)

This is on XP (so no: [VS 2008 Open Web Site takes forever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447346/vs-2008-open-web-site-takes-forever)).

Does anybody have any advice on what else I can check? Unfortunately I have no admin rights on my machine so I can't install other monitoring tools like Sysinternals (or reinstall the OS, and a request for this might happen in weeks, or never).

I didn't really see anything when attaching the debugger while opening a test project. There was a reference to mswsock.dll; does that mean it's trying to call out for something or is it just preparing to run my project locally or some other normal operation?

EDIT: I also tried creating an empty Class Library (i.e., non-Web) project and it takes just as long to load.

What does VS do when loading a project that could change and slow things down to a crawl?

Comment: +1 For documenting your research and spelling out your constraints.  Good luck.

Comment: @ C. Ross: Thanks, anybody who reads the whole thing should get a prize. ;) My concern is that this is one of "those" problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the BusinessObjects Enterprise stuff that's knocking VS down to a slow crawl.

Their .NET SDK does this, and even before I installed that just referencing the relevant assemblies led to a start-up time of 7 minutes for my primary work project.

Their integration with the IDE makes every project--even simple ones with default settings--slow to open.

General Web and SAP forum searches haven't turned up much about this problem, which is confusing (and makes me think I'm doing something incorrectly; yet others on my team now have the same problem).

Has anybody else encountered this problem with BO Enterprise? Anybody using it and not seeing the same issues we are with VS integration?

At this point we don't think we can realistically develop with it. [I posted something over on their forums but haven't received any responses yet.]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are timing out attempting to resolve (or connect to) an invalid hostname.

Check your hosts file (`%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\`) and make sure that `localhost` hasn't been defined as something other than `127.0.0.1` (or `::1` if you're on Windows 7).

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for looking at my question. I checked my hosts file and localhost maps to 127.0.0.1. Any other ideas? All was well until trying to add the BusinessObjects assembly references yesterday.

Comment: If you run `ping localhost` from the commandline, is it `127.0.0.1` that is resolved?

Comment: Yeah, 127.0.0.1. I also just tried creating an empty Class Library project to see if the problem is specific to Web projects, and it also took a long time to open (20 seconds). I don't seem to be having any other system problems; for example I just ran Word and opened a document from a network share without any delays. Something yesterday made VS slow.

Answer (score 2):

I once had performance problems with Visual Studio on XP which turned out to be related to bad proxy settings. In my case, the symptom was a long (at least 10 seconds) delay each time after I stopped a debug session. I don't particularly remember projects taking a long time to load, but that might also have been the case.

Try clearing your proxy settings by running `proxycfg -d` on the command line. That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks Wim, I gave it a try but unfortunately no change. I guess what I really need to understand is exactly what VS does when it opens a project. Something changed yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something Source Control related?  I installed AnkhSVN the other day and now my projects take a much longer time to load.

I might also suspect a virus scanner.  Get cozy with a network admin and have him temporarily disable your virus scanner as a test.

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks, these are all good things to check. I'm seeing the same behavior with new test projects not connected to any source control (unless there's something I'm missing).

I wondered about anti-virus too, but this occurred yesterday and this morning and I haven't noticed any particular processes getting out of hand.

I thought reinstalling VS might help with all this but it didn't (though I wonder what it may have left lying around after the uninstall).

Comment: @tk-421: Can you find out if there was an engine or definition update for your virus scanner in the past day or two?

Comment: It's possible because there's always something going on here, but I won't be able to confirm this due to the size and structure of the organization. ;)

Comment: Anything interesting in Tools->Add-In Manager ?

Comment: It's empty for my test Web project (not enabled for the Class Library project). I tried running devenv.exe /SafeMode and that didn't change anything, but devenv.exe /ResetSettings may have helped--I'll post an update once I know more.

Comment: @Jacob: The resolution is above--in a sense I guess it was like an add-in tool because the BusinessObjects stuff was definitely the problem (and I believe /ResetSettings was removing its IDE integration).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem a couple days ago. The problem was that I had recently moved my working directory, and Visual Studio 2008 was always searching for those missing files. I often had to wait up to a minute after a debug session. I didn't find the solution here, but this is what worked for me:

1. Click on the start button and select "Run...", type in "regedit" to open up the registry editor.
2. Find the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1\ProjectMRUList`
   This is where Visual Studio 2008 stores the lists of recent projects. Delete all 20 of the keys below the first one.
3. Open Visual Studio - there won't be any recent projects, but it will open fast again.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2007/04/08/if-visual-studio-takes-ages-to-load.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the culprit to be the *.NCB file within the project.
I deleted both the *.ncb and the *.suo.
My project now opens in under a 1 second!