# What does Visual Studio 2008 do when I add an assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, assemblies

When I add a reference to an assembly (living in the GAC) to web.config in an ASP.NET project, what does Visual Studio do?

[This is related to an earlier question pertaining to BusinessObjects: [VS2008: Projects now take forever to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379615/) ]

When I add "CrystalDecisions.Enterprise" and "CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework" to the assemblies element in web.config, VS thinks long and hard about it, locking me out for a couple of minutes while it scrutinizes the newcomers.

What is it doing during this time? I Googled this but came up empty.

I can make some educated guesses (IntelliSense integration, perhaps?) but would ideally like to find some documentation describing exactly what's going on.

Ultimately I'm hoping to learn why these BO references are making VS take several minutes to open my projects (I struck out on the SAP forums).

Comment: BTW after VS is finally done churning after adding the references to web.config, trying to add a "using" directive to reference CrystalDecisions.Enterprise results in another minute or two of churning. I'm not happy with BusinessObjects.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you directly with finding documentation but Visual Studio will need to load these assemblies into memory and navigate the assembly structure for many different things, such as Intellisense population, Object Browser, etc. It will also have to potentially load other GAC items that those assemblies depend upon into memory and do similar things.

Comment: Oh, and of course there's a buttload of validations that go on as well to make sure you're able to load these assemblies. Again, I know this is all loose information and you're looking for something more concrete. Good luck with that!

Comment: Thanks, if I can't find specific documentation I'm hoping to at least cobble together information from answers (like yours) provided here. Running a depends check on the CrystalDecisions.Enterprise assembly led to a bunch of references to BO DLLs, so it seems like there's a whole hierarchy of stuff to load up. I just don't understand why I can't find more discussion of this problem--I've certainly Googled it to death. A colleague installed the BO SDK and immediately noticed the same slowness with VS.